# Using Button to change a value - Access

Tags: ms-access, button

I have a form that takes in a class number, and then displays the class roster for the given class.

I am new to Access, so this may be a simple question, but how can I use a Button that is called `Find Class` that can be pressed so the user can change the class number?

Right now, I have `ClassNbr` as a field in my query, and then I am using that field in my report as an `unbound textbox`. It has a default value that is automatically displayed when the form is opened. Is there a way I can use a button to edit this `ClassNbr` field?

Comment: For what purpose? Cannot directly set value of textbox on report. The textbox can call a function that returns a value. The button code can change value of field in table but that serves no purpose if the textbox is not bound to field. The changed value would not immediately be reflected in report already open. Your question is too broad.

Comment: @June7 The purpose would be to allow the user to input the class number of the class they want to see the roster for. Is there another tool I can use aside from an `unbound textbox` to display the class number, and also have a button that allows the user to change this number?

Comment: Apply filter criteria to report with the DoCmd.OpenReport method. User selects class number from combobox on form. Code references the combobox. Or use a dynamic parameterized query as report RecordSource. Do research on OpenReport and its arguments as well as dynamic query. This is really basic Access functionality.